# Magic URL to force a UIWebView to load in MobileSafari instead?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've got an application which has been launched out in the world (so I can't change that version), and I've noticed that certain 3rd-party pages seem to fail when loaded in the native `UIWebView`, but work fine when loaded in the regular Mobile Safari browser.  I know I can change the `UIWebViewDelegate` to send problematic URLs off to Mobile Safari next time I release (and I plan to), but I'm hoping there's some solution for the meantime.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to change the URL I send up from my server which ordinarily would just be loaded by the `UIWebView` so that it causes the `UIWebView` to refuse to load it and pass it off to Mobile Safari instead.  Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if your app version is coded to load a URL inside a `UIWebView` instance, there isn't anyway to mimic sending that URL to `UIApplication`'s `openURL:` instead.

Comment: Ultimately, I came to the same conclusion.  :-(